# Error: Unable to insert the property of the picture class

Tags: excel, vba

This Macro works perfectly when it's on a fresh(empty) workbook but when I try to add it to an existing workbook it throws up the titled error.

It shows img as empty when I break and hover, and I'm not sure why!

Thanks in advance.

```
  Sub Insert_Image()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Submit"
    .Title = "Select an image file"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
    .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
    .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
    .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
    .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
    .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

    If .Show = -1 Then
        Dim img As Object
        Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))
        img.Left = 50
        img.Top = 150
        img.Width = 150
        img.Height = 150
    End If
    End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the worksheet cannot be protected.

Unprotect, fiddle with whatever, protect.

Works as expected.